# Sitecore Upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1 issue: Required license is missing: Runtime

Tags: upgrade, site-configuration, licensing

While upgrading sitecore 8.0 to 8.1. I have follow all the steps of upgrade guide. then i got the error  "Required license is missing: Runtime".

License file is the same as i have used in sitecore 8.0 and at the same place(Data folder).

Please help me on this.

Comment: did you check datafolder setting value using hostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Comment: Check data folder setting may be somehow it's replaced with fresh one

Comment: there is no datafolder setting value in  /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx. there is just single line: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShowConfig.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sitecore.sitecore.admin.ShowConfig" %>

Comment: did you open on the browser this url : hostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx  where hostname is name of the site? you have to login with a admin user

Comment: Catch 22 - showconfig.aspx will not load when the license file is missing

Comment: can use config builder tool (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/sitecore_configbuilder.aspx) to generate the showconfig output

Answer (score 4):

The path to your license file is set incorrectly. The default value of the license file setting in config is:

```
<setting name="LicenseFile" value="$(dataFolder)/license.xml" />
```

If you have not change this, then most likely the issue is the `dataFolder` variable is not set correctly. Use a patch config set to update it to match the folder path your website is deployed to:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sc.variable name="dataFolder">
      <patch:attribute name="value">C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\my-project-location\Data</patch:attribute>
    </sc.variable>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The reason for the failure in your upgrade, at a guess, is that the `dataFolder` variable was updated directly in the `<sitecore>` section of **web.config** before, and when you upgrade to Sitecore 8.1 this has been moved to separate **/App_Config/Sitecore.config** file and therefore you lost your old setting. It's always best to use config patches to override Sitecore settings.

Answer (score 0):

@jammykam 's answer contains all the information about where you can find the dataFolder setting.

In addition to that, you can use *Sitecore ConfigBuilder* tool to build the showconfig output or web.config output.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/sitecore_configbuilder.aspx

Main advantage of this tool is,

- your website does not have to be running to generate the config files
- can be use to generate full web.config output (not only showconfig output -- i.e. not only /configurations/sitecore section)